# Расстановка знаков препинания в тексте по аудиофайлу

Tags: c#, java, c++, аудио

Имеется аудиозапись речевого сообщения и соответствующий текст без каких-либо знаков препинания. Каким образом можно разделить этот текст на предложения и уже в них навести порядок с пунктуацией?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А каким образом аудиозапись поможет? Паузы в речи, например, почти никак не соответствуют знакам препинания: пунктуация отображает скорее логические, чем речевые акценты — что можно видеть даже на этом предложении.